# Where can I find the Flex source code?

Tags: apache-flex, open-source

I keep hearing that Flex is open source and I figured that a great way to learn about the inner workings would be to look at it. I can easily find the Flex SDK (http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Get+Source+Code), but I'm wanting to look at the class definitions for the MXML core library (like NumericStepper). Have I misunderstood, or is this kind of thing available somewhere?

Note, I'm looking for the source of some core MXML components so I can see how they work internally, not for the compiler's source. Does what I've linked above have what I'm looking for and I just can't find it in the director structure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have installed the sdk or Flex builder all of the source files are installed locally on your computer, I believe.

I have flex builder 3 installed source is located here(depending on where you installed):

*Source for flex 3 sdk*

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx

*Source for flex 2 sdk*

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\2.0.1\frameworks\source\mx

Hope this helps and alleviates the need to be online to view the source...

Answer (score 3):

The source is found in the SVN repository that is here:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Get+Source+Code

Answer (score 3):

Here's a direct link to the NumericStepper code: http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/controls/NumericStepper.as

And here's the complete code of the framework: http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/

Answer (score 1):

The open source stuff appears to be at:

```
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads
```

I don't know if everything is available there yet, there may be issues with third-party stuff.